# How to generate typedefinition files from javascript files?

Tags: javascript, typescript, systemjs

I started to programming typescript, but I need some node_modules, that are only in javascript. (@typings/... not working here).

- So, how could I generate from these packages to typescript compatible package?

Because `import 'package-name' from 'package-name';` not working in .ts files. (Err message: Cannot find module). I would like to import like a module, not a file. So I do not want to use this format:

```
import 'package-name' from '../node_modules/package-name/src/package-name.js';
```

In addition, I use SystemJs to load other js files. So I am confusing about this:

- When I have to use SystemJs?
- When I have to use TypeScript import statement?
- Do I have to generate from js to ts everytime or only special cases?

Thanks for the help

Comment: You need to write `.d.ts` files by hand.

Comment: Could you show me an example or a link, especially from node_module?

Comment: http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html